# Restrict Schema Access to Specific IP Address in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to Restrict Schema Access to Specific IP Address,i tried the below code but still this db is accessible to all the ip's .
how can i achive this from below code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system.check_ip_addresses 
AFTER LOGON 
ON DATABASE
DECLARE 
  l_ip_address VARCHAR2(16) := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'); 
BEGIN 
  IF USER IN ('abc') THEN
    IF l_ip_address IN ('189.14.1.54') THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Can not log in from this IP address (' || l_ip_address || ')');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  IF USER IN ('abc') THEN
```

USER will always return the user in uppercase, i.e. 'ABC', unless of course you do something insane and use double quotes when you define the user.

So, change your code to be:

```
  IF USER IN ('ABC') THEN
```

and it should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Mark, i tried your suggestion,but its not working still i am able to connect the database with other ip's .is there any other way to achieve ip restriction

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOSTNAME')
```

The IP_ADDRESS directive does not always work. You can tell by running it within a select, like so:

```
SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')
-------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST')
-------------------------------------------------------------------
orcl.prod
```